# Youtube API v3 Create Youtube Channel on Android with webView

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I am trying to prompt android user to create youtube channel using `WebView` following this use case [Creating Youtube Channel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/create-channel).

So, first, I open `mWebView` using this url `https://m.youtube.com/create_channel?chromeless=1&next=/channel_creation_done`

And then, I have the following code snippet to hide web-view when creation is completed.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if ("https://m.youtube.com/channel_creation_done".equals(url))
             view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
```

However,  after successful channel creation web view url **does not** become `https://m.youtube.com/channel_creation_done` as expected. And user is left with all white `webview` screen.

Has something changed in specifications? Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so to answer my own question, the problem was that the resulting `url` was not **exactly** `https://m.youtube.com/channel_creation_done` because it also had some extra parameters following `?`.

Thus the solution was to use the following line of code

```
 if (url!=null && url.contains("https://m.youtube.com/channel_creation_done"))
             view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```